# Is it possible to track the page the user lands?

Tags: javascript, shopify

What would be a viable way to accomplish the following:

a website has several pages. If the user came to the site from the New Landing page, show a different user journey, else show the regular user journey. Is there a way to track the page the customer lands?

I would need this done in JS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to accomplish this is to use a 3rd party tracker.

I recommend [Voluum](https://voluum.com/), [Thrivetracker](https://thrivetracker.com/) or [Redtrack](https://redtrack.io/) for the same. You can setup the "Flow/Rotation/Stream" of the traffic depending on the campaign link through which the person reaches your website. Each Flow/Rotation/Stream can have several custom landing pages and offers.

If you want a custom solution built, you need to look at [302 redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to redirect users and identifying where the user came from using [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics can be an easy solution for it

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Free: yandex metrica, piwik, google analytics
Paid: heap.io, amplitude, adobe analytics

Comment: Thank you, we have Google Analytics set up to track user interaction. Just wasn't sure how to retrieve the tracking data and use it to show different user journeys. Will look into it.